# Count of more then one different values in a single group when using GROUP BY clause of SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

Consider i have following data in My table.

TableName : Task

```
+---------+
| status  |
+---------+
| open    |
| reopen  |
| reopen  |
| close   |
| suspend |
| close   |
+---------+
```

Now, I want to count record group by its status.
But there is one change that, I want to count **open** and **reopen** like they are in same group.

So I execute this below query.

```
SELECT 
 status,COUNT(*)
FROM 
 Task
GROUP BY status
```

A) What I got.

B) What I want.

```
A)                      B)
+---------+---------+   +---------+---------+
| status  | count   |   | status  | count   |
+---------+---------+   +---------+---------+
| open    | 1       |   | open    | 3       |
| reopen  | 2       |   | close   | 2       |
| close   | 2       |   | suspend | 1       |
| suspend | 1       |   +---------+---------+
+---------+---------+
```

As you can see from above in A) I got the result of the query. **But I want to count record of reopen in open it self.**
That you can see in B).

And one more thing I don't want this count in horizontal order.
Which U have tried. Below Query will work.

```
C) 
SELECT
  COUNT(case status when 'open' then 1 when 'reopen' then 1 else null end) as open
  COUNT(case status when 'close' then 1 else null end) as close,
  COUNT(case status when 'suspend' then 1 else null end) as suspend
FROM
  Task
+---------+---------+---------+
| open    | close   | suspend |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 3       | 2       | 1       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

So My question is How can I achieve B) as I mentioned above without using option C) ?

You can try this sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdf820

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option C is just overkill. All you need to do is convert "reopen" to "open"

```
SELECT   CASE status WHEN 'reopen' THEN 'open' ELSE status END, COUNT(*)
FROM     task
GROUP BY CASE status WHEN 'reopen' THEN 'open' ELSE status END
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all thanx to @Mureinik , and after following his answer

I found that no need to pass the `CASE` in projection.
So this query will also work. May be this one is more efficient.

```
SELECT   status, COUNT(*)
FROM     task
GROUP BY CASE status WHEN 'reopen' THEN 'open' ELSE status END
```